# Connect vertical edge to angled edge

Tags: modeling, edges

How do I connect the vertical part of my railing to the angled part?  I was wondering if there was a way to do this without just eyeballing it.  They are both part of the same object.

[image: Stairs Railing]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the ***knife project*** tool. Duplicate the top face of the vertical *cube* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), place it between two *cubes*, then separate the face (<kbd>P</kbd>). In *Object Mode* select the newly created *plane*, then the angled *cube* and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter the its *Edit Mode*. Go to the *bottom view*, press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and type *Knife Project*. Delete the *plane*. Join objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Join meshes in *Edit Mode* using *Bridge Edge Loops* operation. Finally *dissolve* the horizontal edge with <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Dissolve Edges*.
[image]

Comment: This is a great place for me to start using the knife Project Tool. When trying to follow this example it keeps projecting to the "top" of the angled cube? If you have time I could use some advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using a knife project make sure you're in a *bottom view*. If you're in a top view it will project on top of the angled cube. To project on both sides check the *Cut Trough* checkbox in the Knife Project panel of a Tool Shelf.

Comment: That was it TYVM

Comment: Mind officially blown. Why did I not know this was a thing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I was thinking about Knife project but I thought there might be  a simpler way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of blender easy tools to do that, there is a way using booleans, but if you need a simpler solution, I can't help. Also, I suppose you just need to "snap" the vertical bar top face to the upper bar, not create a connected geometry from the two separate meshes.

Here is the method I said above: in this case, starting from this

[image]

I would go to side ortho view, and duplicate the vertical bar,

[image]

then either move or extrude this copy until it crosses the upper bar, and also scale this copy over X axis (eg: try scaling just a little down over X)

Then, apply to copy mesh a boolean with intersect to the upper bar (the scale over X we made before now helps the boolean), and apply.

[image]

This creates vertices in the copy mesh that may be later used to snap the original vertical bar vertices (extended or extruded).

[image]

After extending or extruding the top vertices of the vertical bar, snapping them to the copy mesh vertices, which are exactly at the intersection you need,

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

you can then delete the copy mesh.

[image]

[image]

Hth

Comment: That's interesting. Will definitely help in future projects.  Wish I could also mar you as a answer.