# How to extend/cut from one mesh to another?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

(I am a beginner)

Hello, I would like to know how to extend or cut a solid until another INCIDENT geometry.

In other words, what I want to know is how to connect these two following solids:
[image]

in this following way:

[image]

Thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: also similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80056/connect-vertical-edge-to-angled-edge/80061#80061

Comment: Also possible with selecting top face of bottom cube, insetting it and using Bridge Edge Loops on it and one bottom of the top mesh.